# Вызов внешней программы

Tags: c++, windows

Язык C++, система Windows. Моей консольной программе необходимо вызвать другой .exe (который тоже выполняется в консоли) в фоновом режиме и передать ему некоторые строковые аргументы. Пожалуйста, не подскажите, как сделать это?

Comment: Есть вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821787/c-program-to-execute-another-program-with-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимальная программа, выполняющая поставленную задачу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

std::stringstream stream;    
stream << "\"C:\\MyProgram\\bin\\Release\\Prg.exe\""
       << " " // разделитель, отделяющий программу от аргумента
       << "myargument";
system(stream.str().c_str());

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаете, если вместо `stringstream` использовать `string` или просто `char []` получится длиннее?

Comment: @avp: Не, нормально будет. Ничем не хуже

Comment: @avp, использовать `char[]` в  C++ - некошерно

Comment: @skegg, да,  а вот такое (интересно, самое короткое?) `int main () { return system((((string("ls") += " ")) + "/tmp").c_str()); }`
 кошерно для крестов (или это уже "лисп")?